# how can I have multiple subscriptions to the same plan at different times in recurly?

Tags: recurly

I need to have multiple subscriptions to the same plan for the same account -- but these may come at different times.

As an example, I have a house-hold of four people.

I have one plan, a Monthly "health tracking plan":

January, Dan gets the plan.

March, Rachel gets the same plan

I would want the invoice to show:

Monthly - Rachel
Monthly - Dan

And have the pro-ration logic apply.  If Dan's subcription started 1st of the month, and Rachel starts 15th, Rachel's first month is prorated from the 15th to the end of the month.

Answer (score 2):

There are two options:

1. Increase the quantity of the original subscription (which handles the proration). Downside: the users are not identified individually

   2. Add a second subscription to the plan (This requires enabling a feature to allow multiple subscriptions to the same plan), and setting a first_renewal_date parameter at creation, which will create a prorated charge. Downside: Customer is billed for each subscription individually, which may not be cost effective with merchant account fees.

Feel free to ping us at [Recurly Support](http://support.recurly.com) if you want to discuss in more detail!

Comment: hm...it would be great for subsequent subscriptions when increasing the quantity to add some kind of an atttribute for each addition.  We want the customer to be billed all at once across all subscriptions on their anniversary date, so #2 is not an option.